# Can Indy load SSL certificates from memory?

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a client app that needs to authorize itself to a server using certificates. The communication is using SSL over TCP (not HTTP/HTTPS related).

I have this working when I use the private key file and set this on the IOHandler, etc.

I would like to avoid having to put the private key file on disk on the client side. Instead, I would like to provide the private key to Indy via memory in some way.

I have not been able to find a way to do this, so now I am wondering if this is at all possible?

Clarification:
My plan is to include the private key in encrypted form as a resource in the `.exe` file, decrypt it in memory, and then feed it to Indy via a stream or buffer. So the question is, does Indy support this in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, Indy does not expose functionality to load certificates from memory. There is an open ticket for that feature request:

> [#150: Support loading OpenSSL certificate/key data from user-defined storage](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/150)

However, OpenSSL does support it, and under D2009+ on Windows, Indy resorts to that functionality in order to load certificate files using UTF-16 filenames, which OpenSSL does not support (on *Nix systems, it does support UTF-8 filenames, though).  Indy loads the files into memory and uses the same parsing functions that OpenSSL itself uses.  So what you are asking for is *possible*, just not *straight forward*.

Here is an example.  These are Indy's `IndySSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file_PKCS12()` and (UTF-16 based) `IndySSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file()` wrapper functions, which `TIdSSLContext.LoadKey()` calls to load the private key file specified in the `TIdSSLOptions.KeyFile` property:

```
function TIdSSLContext.LoadKey: Boolean;
begin
  if PosInStrArray(ExtractFileExt(KeyFile), ['.p12', '.pfx'], False) <> -1 then begin
    Result := IndySSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file_PKCS12(fContext, KeyFile) > 0;
  end else begin
    Result := IndySSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(fContext, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) > 0;
  end;
  if Result then begin
    Result := SSL_CTX_check_private_key(fContext) > 0;
  end;
end;

function IndySSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file_PKCS12(ctx: PSSL_CTX; const AFileName: String): TIdC_INT;
var
  LM: TMemoryStream;
  B: PBIO;
  LKey: PEVP_PKEY;
  LCert: PX509;
  P12: PPKCS12;
  CertChain: PSTACK_OF_X509;
  LPassword: array of TIdAnsiChar;
  LPasswordPtr: PIdAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := 0;

  LM := nil;
  try
    LM := TMemoryStream.Create;
    LM.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
  except
    // Surpress exception here since it's going to be called by the OpenSSL .DLL
    // Follow the OpenSSL .DLL Error conventions.
    SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_CTX_USE_PRIVATEKEY_FILE, ERR_R_SYS_LIB);
    LM.Free;
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    B := BIO_new_mem_buf(LM.Memory, LM.Size);
    if not Assigned(B) then begin
      SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_CTX_USE_PRIVATEKEY_FILE, ERR_R_BUF_LIB);
      Exit;
    end;
    try
      SetLength(LPassword, MAX_SSL_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1);
      LPassword[MAX_SSL_PASSWORD_LENGTH] := TIdAnsiChar(0);
      LPasswordPtr := PIdAnsiChar(LPassword);
      if Assigned(ctx^.default_passwd_callback) then begin
        ctx^.default_passwd_callback(LPasswordPtr, MAX_SSL_PASSWORD_LENGTH, 0, ctx^.default_passwd_callback_userdata);
        // TODO: check return value for failure
      end else begin
        // TODO: call PEM_def_callback(), like PEM_read_bio_X509() does
        // when default_passwd_callback is nil
      end;
      P12 := d2i_PKCS12_bio(B, nil);
      if not Assigned(P12) then begin
        SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_CTX_USE_PRIVATEKEY_FILE, ERR_R_PKCS12_LIB);
        Exit;
      end;
      try
        CertChain := nil;
        if PKCS12_parse(P12, LPasswordPtr, LKey, LCert, @CertChain) <> 1 then begin
          SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_CTX_USE_CERTIFICATE_FILE, ERR_R_PKCS12_LIB);
          Exit;
        end;
        try
          Result := SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey(ctx, LKey);
        finally
          sk_pop_free(CertChain, @X509_free);
          X509_free(LCert);
          EVP_PKEY_free(LKey);
        end;
      finally
        PKCS12_free(P12);
      end;
    finally
      BIO_free(B);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LM);
  end;
end;

function IndySSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx: PSSL_CTX; const AFileName: String;
  AType: Integer): TIdC_INT;
var
  LM: TMemoryStream;
  B: PBIO;
  LKey: PEVP_PKEY;
  j: TIdC_INT;
begin
  Result := 0;

  LM := nil;
  try
    LM := TMemoryStream.Create;
    LM.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
  except
    // Surpress exception here since it's going to be called by the OpenSSL .DLL
    // Follow the OpenSSL .DLL Error conventions.
    SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_CTX_USE_PRIVATEKEY_FILE, ERR_R_SYS_LIB);
    LM.Free;
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    B := BIO_new_mem_buf(LM.Memory, LM.Size);
    if not Assigned(B) then begin
      SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_CTX_USE_PRIVATEKEY_FILE, ERR_R_BUF_LIB);
      Exit;
    end;
    try
      case AType of
        SSL_FILETYPE_PEM:
          begin
            j := ERR_R_PEM_LIB;
            LKey := PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(B, nil,
              ctx^.default_passwd_callback,
              ctx^.default_passwd_callback_userdata);
          end;
        SSL_FILETYPE_ASN1:
          begin
            j := ERR_R_ASN1_LIB;
            LKey := d2i_PrivateKey_bio(B, nil);
          end;
      else
        SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_CTX_USE_PRIVATEKEY_FILE, SSL_R_BAD_SSL_FILETYPE);
        Exit;
      end;
      if not Assigned(LKey) then begin
        SSLerr(SSL_F_SSL_CTX_USE_PRIVATEKEY_FILE, j);
        Exit;
      end;
      Result := SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey(ctx, LKey);
      EVP_PKEY_free(LKey);
    finally
      BIO_free(B);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LM);
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, Indy loads the certificate file into a `BIO` using `BIO_new_mem_buf()`, extracts an `EVP_PKEY` from it, and passes it to OpenSSL's `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey()` function to load the key into the session's `SSL_CTX` object (Indy does not support RSA/ASN1 private keys at this time).

So, you would have to adopt similar logic into your own code.  Of course, you would have to make your code get invoked at the correct time, and for that you would need to modify Indy's source code to add your code to `TIdSSLContext.LoadKey()` and then recompile Indy.  At least until Indy exposes native access in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

If the Indy code will accept a stream, you can easily load anything you could load from a file from a `TMemoryStream` instead, but that doesn't resolve the question of how you load a certificate into the `TMemoryStream` in the first place.

What it all comes down to is that your program will have to load the certificate at some point, either from disc or from the network, before it can have it in memory.  You could embed it as a resource into the EXE itself and load it with a TResourceStream, but that still counts as it being on disc, because it's part of the EXE.  And loading it over the network means you have a server somewhere that's *serving up your private key,* so that's not a good idea for obvious reasons.  There's really no way around having your private key on disc somewhere; just make sure your server's configured in a way that it can't serve that file up as a download.

Comment: Thanks. I was already thinking along those lines. I have added a clarification to my question.